# Infinite digest error on filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
$scope.arr = [
    {'val': true},
    {'val': false},
    {'val': false},
    {'val': true},
    {'val': false},
]
```

I am using `ng-repeat` with a filter which sorts the array on the basis of the key 'val' and puts the objects with 'val' set to true before other objects. Here's the filter:

```
app.filter('ownerFirst', [function() {
    return function(list) {
        list.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a['val'] - b['val'];
        })
        return list;
    }
}])
```

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in arr | ownerFirst">
```

But I am getting an [infinite digest error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:214,%22oldVal%22:210%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:218,%22oldVal%22:214%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:222,%22oldVal%22:218%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:226,%22oldVal%22:222%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bvar%20e%3Da(c,d);return%20b(e,c,d)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:230,%22oldVal%22:226%7D%5D%5D). Why is this happening?

Comment: try this one <div ng-repeat="obj in arr  track by $index| ownerFirst">

Comment: If I do that, I will have to pass arr as a parameter to the 'ownerFirst' filter. Neverthless, let me try...

Comment: You sort the array on every iteration. Try to sort your array before the ng-repeat.

Comment: I can do that, but I am asking why am I getting the error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom filter, try using [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in arr | orderBy: '-val'">
```

You'll need to put the `-`-sign in front of `val` because you want a descending sort.

Comment: Thanks. Is the '-' just before val for reverse sorting?